# How to create a column in multiple dataframes based on their names?

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have multiple data.frames named as below. Each of them has some data for each year (2018, 2019, 2020 and 2021):

```
subset_2018_empenhada
subset_2019_empenhada
subset_2020_empenhada
subset_2021_empenhada
```

I want to create a column in each of them named "ANO" and I need that the values of these columns for each data frame be the year in his name.
For example: considering the data.frame "subset 2018_empenhada", the new column "ANO" must have the values 2018 in all rows

| data | ANO |
| --- | --- |
| 64646464 | 2018 |
| 45454755 | 2018 |

Considering the "subset_2019_empenhada"
| data| ANO |
| -------- | ---- |
| 34646| 2019|
| 44785| 2019|

I know how to do that one by one, using `data$ANO <- 2018`.

However, I sometimes work with a lot of data, and I believe doing all at once would be better and faster.

I though something with `lapply`, but I couldn't advance.

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We get the objects in a `list` with `mget`, loop over the list with `imap` and create the column by extracting the year part from the list names and if it needs to update the original objects, use `list2env`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
mget(ls(pattern = "^subset_\\d{4}_empenhada$")) %>%
   imap(~ .x %>%   
               mutate(ANO = str_extract(.y, "\\d{4}"))) %>%
   list2env(.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: What if I have data.frames with other things besides "empenhado"? For example: subset_2018_empenhada
subset_2019_liquidado
subset_2020_liquidado
subset_2021_empenhada

Comment: @DaniloImbimbo if it is not specific you can change the `pattern` to `pattern = "^subset_\\d{4}_.*"`